# Insert multiple glyphs at once

Tags: adobe-indesign, glyphs, batch-processing

In InDesign you can insert a glyph by double clicking on it in the glyph palette window. What I would like to do is insert multiple glyphs or all the glyphs of a font at once without having to always double click on each glyph.
Is it possible? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have the impression that you're trying to “type” using the glyph panel. If so, you should instead try to find some suitable input method on an OS level (maybe custom keyboard layout). Could you please give some information about the OS you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wonderful script to type all the characters of a font at once: http://indesignsecrets.com/make-a-font-contact-sheet-in-indesign.php